# XGBoost best max_depth=1

Tags: xgboost

I use xgboost to train a classification model. GridCVSearch gives the best max_depth=1. This means all my hundreds of trees are split at a single node.

Does this mean that the problem/dataset that I work with is separable using simple models and I don't need to use complicated model such as xgboost?

In general, if all the trees have depth 1, does xgboost provide better prediction than simple models such as SVM/logistic regression?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You arrive at ADABoost not even close to regular decision trees

ADABoost: Each tree has a depth of 1(weak learners)

Its about the your features not necessarily model, if you have few features then it does not make sense to go so deep in each tree

Answer (score -2):

If Depth is 1 means you arrived with a regular decision tree and losts the advantage of XGBOOST.

Comment: I don't agree. Xgboost has a unique way of splitting, namely not by the SSR as a regular tree, but by a combination of gain (gradient) and cover (hessian). See [this video](https://youtu.be/OtD8wVaFm6E?t=247) and [the official documentation](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/model.html). You would still retain the advantages of e.g. custom loss, speed. Also, a stump (depth of 1) is still a non-linear model and you're building many of them, so the result should be better than a single tree. For example AdaBoost uses mostly stumps as got better results than linear models.